# How to pass data (array and number in this case) as a prop to another route in vue?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-props

So i have a routing set up in my Vue application and i have a **HomeView** view and a **CheckoutView** view and i want to pass the data as a prop from *HomeView ("/")* to *CheckoutView ("/checkout")* but i cant find a way to do it since they have no connections. To be exact, i want to send the `cart` array and `total` value from *HomeView* to *CheckoutView* everytime user requests **"/checkout"** route.

**router/index.js**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: '/checkout',
    name: 'checkout',
    component: () => import('../views/CheckoutView.vue')
  }
]
```

**HomeView.vue**

```
export default {
import productsData from '@/assets/products.json';

  name: 'HomeView',
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      cart: [],
      total: 0,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.products = productsData;
  }
}
```

**CheckoutView.vue**

```
export default {
  name: "CheckoutView",
  props: {
    cart: Array,
    total: Number
  }
}
```

I obviously simplified the code to only essentials but to sum everything up: with every request to route **"/checkout"** i want the `cart` and `total` from *HomeView* to be sent as props to *CheckoutView*.

Comment: You should look into global state management solutions, if you are using Vue 2 try vuex, if this is Vue 3 project try Pinia. Usually cart item data or similar logics are placed in a global state, but you might need to persist data after page reload so you may need to store this in a localstorage but this may get complex if you want to persist cart data per user on login, you need to save user cart data using API calls which will use you backend DB for storing these data.

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanBaji i dont need to keep anything on reload and im trying to do it without global state managment system because it is a small project.. btw im using vue 3

Comment: if the components are unrelated, then there is no other option than to create some sort of global state.  You don't technically _need_ a global state management library like Pinia if the use case is very simple. The [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api) explains how a simple global state pattern can be achieved. For anything beyond the super simple, get Pinia.

Comment: @russelhd, great If you are using Vue 3 and doesn't want an State Management solution like Pinia, you can easily achieve this by exporting a reactive state using ref/reactive. You can keep a state in a seperate file, all component's importing this state will be sharing this state. I will post this as an answer.

Comment: @russelhd i'm on it, done a such thing in one of my previous objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily with Vue 3. Based on your comments, it seems like you're looking for a straight forward solution without using state management tools like pinia or vuex. Here's what you can do: create a file called `cart.js` and put it inside a folder named `store`. Inside that file, handle all the logic related to your global cart state (using ref and reactive), then export it.

Here is an example,
`cart.js`

```js
import { reactive } from "vue";

export const cart = reactive([]);

export const addToCart = (item) => {
  cart.push(item);
};
```

You can now import this state logics from `cart.js` to any of your page components.

Check this [demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-simple-cart-demo-mndjts)